# Transaction won't be rolled back with RuntimeException

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I have currently a code similar to the one below but it does not behave as intented. My assumption is that the parent `Person` will be saved, but the child `Person` should be rolled back.

But that is not happening. **Both** persons are persisted in the DB.

Can someone please explain me why this is and how to make it running as planned?

```
/**
 * This will create one physical transaction PT1, and within a logical transaction LT1.
 */
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void insertParentPerson() {
    System.out.println(getCurrentMethod());
    
    final Person person = getNewPerson();

    save(person);
    
    try {
        insertChildPerson();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException noSuchElementException) {
        System.out.println("Catching child exception");
    }
}

/**
 * This transaction lives in the same physical transaction (PT1) as its parent but has an own logical transaction LT2
 */
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void insertChildPerson() {
    System.out.println(getCurrentMethod());

    final Person person = getNewPerson();

    save(person);

    throw new NoSuchElementException("Random Exception");
}
```

Comment: 1. You are calling an internal method, that won't work with proxies, 2 you are catching the exception so it won't rollback the outer transaction.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no exception thrown out of the method, so the insertParentPerson() ends normally and hence commits the transaction normally.

Second of all, the @Transactional annotation on the second method is not taken into consideration when the method is called from the same class but only when it is called from outside (since the proxied class is not called then)